# JSON - Sum values by date using php

Tags: php, json

I'm creating a simple script in php and json, however I have some difficulties to make Sums of multi values by date.
I want Sum "Import" and "Export" from each month.

This is what I want to print:

```
array (
  'Date'   => '2019-03',
  'Import' => 1000,
  'Export' => 250,
)
array (
  'Date'   => '2019-04',
  'Import' => 100,
  'Export' => 600,
)
```

My json:

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "200",
    "Export": "50"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "800",
    "Export": "200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-04",
    "Import": "100",
    "Export": "600"
  }
]
```

This is my script php:

```
$url = dirname(__DIR__  ) . '/admin/json/all.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array_origin = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$stack=array(); 
foreach ($array_origin as $index => $array_part) {
  $stack[$array_part['Date']] =array_key_exists($array_part['Date'],$stack)?$stack[$array_part['Date']]+$array_part['Import']:$array_part['Import'];
}

echo '<pre>' . var_export($stack, true) . '</pre>';
```

However with this script Im only able to Sum 'Import', but I want also Sum 'export'.

For that reason Im looking for your help.
I appreciate for any help from you guys.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Import` and `Export` keys to the result array.  I've attempted to shorten it and used `isset`:

```
foreach ($array_origin as $v) {
    $stack[$v['Date']]['Import'] = isset($v['Date']) ? $stack[$v['Date']]['Import'] + $v['Import'] : $v['Import'];
    $stack[$v['Date']]['Export'] = isset($v['Date']) ? $stack[$v['Date']]['Export'] + $v['Export'] : $v['Export'];
}
```

Comment: Prefect. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, allow me ask you, if I want make a average of the "Import"?

Comment: `array_column($stack, 'Import')` then `array_sum` / `count`

Comment: Thanks for you help, I appreciate so much :)