# how to merge data of same array in single array of multidimensional array on behalf of date

Tags: php, arrays

I'm learning to work with an array, I have an array in which I have a starting date and a payment amount in every array which I try to merge the same date array in one array and add their payment amount in one array
**this exiting array**

```
array:4 [
  0 => array[
    "payment_amount" => 100
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ]
  1 => array[
    "payment_amount" => 200
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ]
  2 => array[
    "payment_amount" => 300
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ]
  3 => array[
    "payment_amount" => -200
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-17"
  ]
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
array:2 [
      0 => array[
        "payment_amount" => 600
        "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
      ]
      1 => array[
        "payment_amount" => -200
        "starting_date" => "2021-06-17"
      ]
    ]
```

**This is my script code which I try to merge the array**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/test/data',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            data.sort(function(a,b){
                return new Date(a.starting_date) - new Date(b.starting_date);
              });
            testarray(data) 
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });
```

My php code

```
 $sortarray = [];
        $previewsdate = 0;
        $newsdate = 0;
        for ($i=0;$i <count($result);$i++) {
            $previewsdate = $result[$i]['starting_date'];
            echo "previewsdate ".$newsdate.'<br>';
            if ($result['0']['starting_date'] === $previewsdate) {
                $newsdate = $previewsdate;
                echo "first date".$newsdate.'<br>';
                array_push($sortarray, $result[$i]);
           }
            else if ($newsdate === $previewsdate) {
                $newone = array_merge( $result[$i], $result[$i-1]);
                $newsdate = $previewsdate;
               print_r($newsdate);
                echo "next datekjkjkj ".$newsdate.'<br>';
                array_push($sortarray, $newone);
           }
           else if ($newsdate !== $previewsdate) {
            $newsdate = $previewsdate;
            echo "next date ".$newsdate.'<br>';
            array_push($sortarray, $result[$i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: except you're not trying to merge the array at all. You're sorting it. Have you made an attempt at merging? Pls show it.

Comment: check I update the merge code in question but its not working @Kinglish

Comment: Do you need this to sort in php? You don't have that tag in your question

Comment: probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195916/associative-array-sum-values-of-the-same-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON - Sum values by date using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578321/json-sum-values-by-date-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this

```
$a = [
  0 => [
    "payment_amount" => 100,
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ],
  1 => [
    "payment_amount" => 200,
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ],
  2 => [
    "payment_amount" => 300,
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-16"
  ],
  3 => [
    "payment_amount" => -200,
    "starting_date" => "2021-06-17"
  ],
];
$p = array();
foreach($a as $row){
if(array_key_exists($row['starting_date'], $p)){
$p[$row['starting_date']] = $p[$row['starting_date']] + $row['payment_amount'];
}else{
$p[$row['starting_date']] = $row['payment_amount'];
}
}

$finalArr = array();
foreach($p as $dateKey => $totalAmount){
$temp = array();
$temp['payment_amount'] = $totalAmount;
$temp['starting_date'] = $dateKey;
array_push($finalArr, $temp);
}
```

**And you will get final result in $finalArr**

Comment: probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195916/associative-array-sum-values-of-the-same-key)